# Integrate a C# procedure in ASP.NET 4.8 in a project with Razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm stuck in a project with ASP.NET with Razor pages. I'm trying to connect a button to a controller function and the click on the button always jumps to the `Index()` method, and not to the `UploadFile()` method, in my controller.

Upload.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Upload", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="submit" id="uploadbtn" class="btn btn-primary" value="UploadFiles"/>
}
```

UploadController

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFiles()
    {
        string folderPath = @"C:\files\";
        string containerName = "fileupload";
        string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https; AccountName=storage;AccountKey=.....;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

        var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xlsx");

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filePathOverCloud = file.Replace(folderPath, string.Empty);

            try
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file));
                containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(filePathOverCloud, stream);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        return View("Index");
    }
                
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried many things but it does not want to work ... can someone help me please?

Comment: `MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file));` <-- There is no reason to do this (loading an entire file into memory is inefficient), use a `FileStream` instead.

Comment: Also, **never** have an empty `catch` block: _never swallow exceptions_, especially in a catch-all block , at the very least only catch _expected exceptions_ instead of having a catch-all, or have a catch-all block that logs the exception details and re-throws it.

Comment: Hi Dai, I have not finished the catch yet, I will do that as soon as the rest is up and running. Using a FileStream is a good hint, thank you very much, but do you also have an idea for my problem?